# An alternative for tasklist_lock in a module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

For learning purposes I would like to iterate through all the tasks
in a module and output different information about them. For this task
I need to lock the list of all tasks (I'm also unsure if I should do it.). I've seen some example
in the kernel code which lock tasklist_lock. However this symbol
cannot be used by modules. Its export was removed by
c59923a15c12d2b3597af913bf234a0ef264a38b commit.

Is there any other way I can lock the list of tasks then?

Comment: Which kernel version are you working on?

Comment: @ciphor On last stable release - v3.2.2. But I do not see how it can make the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stop_machine()` introduces idle threads and disables interrupts in each of the system's CPUs except for the one that executes the user-defined function you pass as an argument to `stop_machine()`. This is equivalent to holding each spinlock in the kernel and results in a system freeze for as long as the user-defined function runs. Needless to say, it has heavy performance impact, but also provides strong consistency guarantees.

If you want to just read data from the system's tasks and you don't mind absolute preciseness (consistency) you can iterate through the accounting list of processes while in a [read-copy-update (RCU)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/x490.html) critical section. You can also check [RCU in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update).

```
struct task_struct *iter;
rcu_read_lock();
list_for_each_entry_rcu(iter, &init_task.tasks, tasks) {
   printf("The current task of the list is: %s\n.", iter->comm);
}
rcu_read_unlock();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stop_machine() as follows:

```
int for_each_task(void * data)
{
  struct task_struct * g, * p;
  do_each_thread(g, p) {
    // do the work
  } while_each_thread(g, p);
  return 0;
}

...
stop_machine(for_each_task, NULL, NULL);
...
```

`stop_machine` interface suspends all the tasks and puts high-priority thread on each CPUs. So, while in callback no other tasks are scheduled.